# JQuery - Toggle Effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a toggle effect to my element.

It toggles properly, but without an effect. Does the effect only show up with divs? Here is my code:

```js
$(".toggler").click(function(event) {
  var clickedElement = $(event.target);
  $(clickedElement).parent().parent().next("tr").find("td").toggle("slow", 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="details" style="display: none;" colspan="6">
  <p>This is an example column...</p>
  <p>This is an example column...</p>
</td>


<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><a class="toggler">First</a></th>
      <th><a class="toggler">Second</a></th>
      <th><a class="toggler">Third</a></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where is 'toggler' in your HTML?

Comment: It's inside of a tables "th"-tag. However, like I mentioned, the toggling itself is working.

Comment: where is this element `$(".toggler")`? paste full html code.

Comment: Please include a working snippet so we can see the problem. We need to see the code for all elements involved. [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters for jQuery `toggle()` are `speed`, `easing` and `callback`. You are trying to pass the speed in the first and also in the second parameter. It should be either `toggle(1000);` or `toggle("slow");`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use jQuery UI for extended toggle effect options: https://jqueryui.com/toggle/

For a simple fade, try using .fadeToggle() which is included in the base jQuery library: http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, my mistake was, that I used a slim version of JQuery from the bootstrap cdn.

Fixed it by using the normal one.

Comment: you should mark an answer as accepted, so people know that you have figured it out. It could be your own.